# Image of domain under map $f(z) = z^6$?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, exponentiation

I am given the domain $\Omega := \{z \in \mathbb{C}: \operatorname{Im}(z) > \sqrt{3}|\operatorname{Re}(z)|\}$. I want to know what the image $f(\Omega)$ of this domain is under the mapping $f(z)=z^6$. I'm not sure if my method is correct, here is my attempt:

Having sketched the domain, I think I can rewrite $\Omega$ as:
$$\Omega = \{z=re^{i\theta} \in \mathbb{C}: r>0, \frac{\pi}{3} < \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}\} \cup \{z=re^{i\theta} \in \mathbb{C}: r>0, \frac{\pi}{2} < \theta < \frac{2\pi}{3}\}$$
Then, using the reasoning that $f$ sends $z=re^{i\theta}$ to $z^6=r^6e^{6\theta i}$, I have said that the domain is mapped to:
$$f(\Omega) = \{z=re^{i\theta} \in \mathbb{C}: r>0, 2\pi < \theta \leq 3\pi\} \cup \{z=re^{i\theta} \in \mathbb{C}: r>0, 3\pi < \theta < 4\pi\}$$
which I am interpreting as: if $f(\Omega)$ was a sketch on the complex plane, it would be the whole plane minus the positive real axis.

Is this correct? If it is, is there a quicker or more intuitive/interesting way to arrive here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but I'm a bit confused by your description of the domain. Surely the union of those two sets is simply
$$\Omega=\{re^{i\theta}:\ r>0,\ \tfrac13\pi<\theta<\tfrac23\pi\}.$$
Either way, your reasoning from here is correct, and then the image $f(\Omega)$ can similarly be described simply as
$$f(\Omega)=\{re^{i\theta}:\ r>0,\ 2\pi<\theta<4\pi\},$$
which is indeed the entire complex plane minus the positive real axis. Also, don't forget that you're missing $0\in\Bbb{C}$ is well; perhaps it would be less ambiguous to say that it's the entire complex plane minus the *nonnegative* real axis.

---

Another way to see this, though less rigorously, is to note that $\Omega$ is an open region bounded by two half-lines. These two half-lines are both mapped to the nonnegative real axis, and so $\Omega$ is mapped to an open region bounded by the nonnegative real axis. This must then be precisely $\Bbb{C}$ minus the nonnegative real axis. This can of course be made rigorous as well.

[Here](https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/erxesu9j)'s an interactive piece of geometry that shows what $f(\Omega)$ looks like for $f(z)=z^a$, as $a$ varies. The red region is the part of $f(\Omega)$ that is inside the unit disk. It breaks at $a=6$, unfortunately.